# .Net Core Web Api with Nlog event properties for unhandled exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

I was wondering if there is a way to use event properties with unhandled exception in .net core web api with NLog?

Here is my code sample

API controller action

```
[HttpGet("ThrowError")]
public void ThrowError()
{
    throw new Exception("My Test Exception");
}
```

Nlog.config target

```
 <target xsi:type="Mail"
      name="mailserver1"
      html="true"
      replaceNewlineWithBrTagInHtml="true"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      subject="Attention Error!!!"
      body="MyValue: ${event-properties:item=MyValue} ${newline} &lt;strong&gt;Date:&lt;/strong&gt; ${date} ${newline} &lt;strong&gt;Message:&lt;/strong&gt; ${message} ${newline} &lt;strong&gt;Exception:&lt;/strong&gt; ${exception:tostring}"
      to=""
      from=""
      smtpServer=""
      smtpUsername=""
      smtpPort=""
      enableSsl=""
      smtpAuthentication=""
      smtpPassword=""/>
```

As you can see in email body attribute, I event property called MyValue. I can easily set My value with below code for handled exception

```
LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(NLog.LogLevel.Error, "", "Pass my custom value");
theEvent.Properties["MyValue"] = "My custom string";
logger.Log(theEvent);
```

However, for unexpected/unhandled error (eg. calling ThrowError API action in above sample code) NLog automatically sends email and I do not have event property value set.

I tried middleware code like below but exception gets logged before middleware code gets called

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
            {
                errorApp.Run(async context =>
                {
                    var errorFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    var exception = errorFeature.Error;

                    var serviceProvider = app.ApplicationServices;

                    var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
                    LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(NLog.LogLevel.Error, "", exception.StackTrace);
                    theEvent.Properties["MyValue"] = "My custom string";
                    logger.Log(theEvent);
                });
            });
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Custom Layout renderer to populate the value and on nlog.config side used 'when' layout renderer to avoid my custom layout renderer getting called multiple times